# Question on oscillation of Electric field vector

Tags: electric-fields, polarization

I was reading [Feynman Lectures on Physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_33.html) in which he explains the direction of oscillation of electric field vector. If you see figure 33-2 g , you will find that
$E_x = \cos \omega t$
$E_y = \sin \omega t$
So, vector $\mathbf E = \cos (\omega t) \mathbf i + \sin (\omega t) \mathbf j$
Modulus of $E = \sqrt{\cos^2(\omega t) + \sin^2(\omega t)}$
Modulus of $E = 1$

But as you can see he has made a circle, how can I get a circle? I know I'm mistaking somewhere but I'm unable to find it.

Comment: You have all the data, make a sketch.

Comment: @my2cts should I plot E versus t? I’m getting a constant straight line.

Comment: Try something else then.

Comment: I don't understand why you think it shouldn't be a circle

Answer (score 1):

What you describe with these equations is the special case of so called "circular polarization". For a plane wave propagating along $z$, the components $E_x$ and $E_y$ are independent,  so you can choose $E_x(t)=E_0 \cos(\omega t)$ and $E_y=0$ to represent a linear polaristion along the $x$ axis. In the same way $E_x(t)=E_1 \cos(\omega t)$ and $E_y(t)=E_2 \cos( \omega t)$ will represent a linear polarisation along an axis located in the $x-y$ plane and making an angle $\theta$ with the $x$- axis such that $\tan\theta=E_2/E_1$.

The key point here in that $E_x$ and $E_y$ are in phase. If you allow an oscillation out of phase like$E_x(t)=E_1 \cos(\omega t)$ and $E_y(t)=E_2 \cos( \omega t-\phi)$ you get the general case of elliptical polarisation.

The circular polarisation , where the relative phase is $\phi=\pi/2$  ( two components in "quadrature") and $E_1=E_2$ is a special case of elliptical polarisation.

Comment: Technically $E_x$ and $E_y$ are $\pi/2$ out of phase